# Wicket replacing panel with ajax fails with MarkupNotFoundException

Tags: ajax, wicket

the page markup has

```
<div wicket:id="stepPanel" />
```

tag in it and when the page is first loaded it works great that is

```
add(new MyFirstPanel("stepPanel"));
```

works fine. But then when I trigger an Ajax event and request redrawing

```
addOrReplace(new MySecondPanel("stepPanel"));
target.add(MyPage.this);
```

i get the following error

```
Last cause: Failed to find markup file associated. MyFirstPanel: [MyFirstPanel [Component id = stepPanel]]
```

please note that it tries to find the wrong markup (should look for markup for MySecondPanel) and it fails regardless it succedded to do so before!

I instantiate panels using reflection, but could it be a problem here? No exceptions thrown.

**Anwser:**
Actually it was something else - I have noticed that one of my AjaxSubmitLinks had reference to a form that was no longer placed in a markup... so whatever you do just remember not to leave that  reference.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding MyPage after replacing the Panel causing MyPage to re-render.
There is a good example on how to replace panels [here](http://www.solvedo.com/tips/wicket-how-to-replace-a-panel-with-ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can call panels via reflection. I don't clearly know what you are trying to do with event here but if you want you can attach your panel with `AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior` and define the duration which will update this component in the given time period.

Hope its useful.